# If $G$ is an acyclic graph, then every subgraph of $G$ is acyclic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If $G$ is an acyclic graph, then every subgraph of $G$ is acyclic.

Suggestions for this exercise.

Comment: It's obvious, if you think about what it says.

Comment: Forget about graphs and cycles. Think for a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had a cyclic sub-graph $G'$ of $G$. Then there would be some cycle in $G'$. This cycle would also be a cycle in $G$, contradicting the hypothesis that $G$ is acyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if there were no elephants in England, then there would certainly not be any elephants in London, or Manchester, or any other English city. Generalize.